@sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare reveals server-side code in a sourcemap. How to disable?
I’m developing a site with SvelteKit, Cloudflare Pages Functions, and @sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare.
I noticed the sourcemap for my server-side Pages Functions is uploaded and is accessible at mydomain.com/_worker.js.map. This reveals the server-side source code for my Pages Functions, which is a security issue.
How do I disable this behaviour? Either by not producing server-side sourcemaps at all, or not making them publicly accessible. (_worker.js is not publicly accessible, but _worker.js.map is).
I tried setting upload_source_maps = false in wrangler.toml but that has no effect. The project is built and deployed by Cloudflare on their servers on every push to github.

This appears to be fixed by removing the routes key from svelte.config.js
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            // See below for an explanation of these options
            // routes: {
            //     include: ["/api/*"],
            //     exclude: ["<all>"],
            // },
            fallback: "spa",
            platformProxy: {
                configPath: "wrangler.toml",
                environment: undefined,
                experimentalJsonConfig: false,
                persist: true,
            },
        }),
    },
}

export default config

